# Excel rounding same number in different way

Tags: excel, rounding

I've experienced this issue with Excel:
If I remove some decimal digits to the same number (obtained by two different formulas) I get two different rounded numbers. The number `-0,0195` is rounded to `-0,020` when obtained by `0,43930` - `0,45880` while is rounded to `-0,019` when obtained by `1,09230` - `1,11180`.

Can someone explain to me this behaviour? (I know I can use the formula ROUNDUP to solve but I need to investigate the question.)

Comment: You need to provide more details about where the numbers are coming from. One possible reason is the precision of the inputted numbers causeing tiny fractions to make the number not exactly equal to 0.0195 (e.g. 0.0194999999999999999 would be displayed as 0.01950

Comment: Originale numbers (e.g. 1,11180) are simply typed with the keyboard

Comment: Please edit your question to include how they are entered and what functions you are usin for calculations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have come across what's called "Floating Point Precision". 
The two things that affects this "issue" are:

- Excel can only handle 15 digits
- The IEEE 754 floating-point standard requires that numbers be stored in binary format.

*"The IEEE 754 floating-point standard requires that numbers be stored in binary format. This means a conversion must occur before the numbers can be used in calculations. If the number can be represented exactly in floating-point format, then the conversion is exact. "*
Source: [Understanding Floating Point Precision, aka “Why does Excel Give Me Seemingly Wrong Answers?](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/blog/2008/04/10/understanding-floating-point-precision-aka-why-does-excel-give-me-seemingly-wrong-answers/)

*"The IEEE has a standard, IEEE 754, for how to represent floating point numbers in binary, and this is what almost everybody uses, including Excel, and they have for a really long time, and it means sometimes you get imprecise results when you add a lot of 0.1’s together, but if you’re rounding the numbers to a reasonable number of decimal points, you won’t really care."*
Source: [Explain the Excel Bug](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2007/09/26/explaining-the-excel-bug/)

Therefore you can obtain results that seems wrong. It more likely to occur when you add or subtract multiple decimal values. I have illustrated it in the picture below:

[image: Floating Point Precision Issue Illustrated]

There are two easy way to adjust Excel for this behaviour:

1. Use `round()` to round your numbers and increase the number of digits shown.
2. In Excel Option menu -> Advanced -> click "Set precision as displayed".
   The result will be as followed:

[image]

Comment: many thanks for your exhaustive explanation, by the way the workaround you suggest doesn't work for me...

Comment: Fun to help :)!
Thanks for mention it. I just tried the solutions in Excel 2016. Seems you need to have to increase the number of digits (4 digits worked for me) in the cell to make any effect. Then both will behave similar. I have updated my answer to reflect that :)